# httpRequest.GetResponseAsync() fails in windows universal app when used by backgroundTask?

Tags: c#, .net, win-universal-app, background-task

I have the following code that i can call from my universal app, and it works fine

```
// create our request with our data
var data = new JsonObject();
data.Add("param", JsonValue.CreateStringValue("abc"));

// convert to bytes
var dataAsBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data.Stringify());

var httpRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(URL + "Add");
httpRequest.Method = "POST";
httpRequest.ContentType = "application/json;charset=utf-8";

using (var requestStream = await httpRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync())
{
    requestStream.Write(dataAsBytes, 0, dataAsBytes.Length);    
}

var httpResponse = await httpRequest.GetResponseAsync();

using (var responseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream()) {
    ....
}
```

But this code seems to stop on `var httpResponse = await httpRequest.GetResponseAsync()` when i execute this from a backgroundTask?

To setup my background task, i have the following code.

```
var taskRegistered = false;
var taskName = "Upload Background Task";
var background = Windows.ApplicationModel.Background;
var iter = background.BackgroundTaskRegistration.allTasks.first();

while (iter.hasCurrent) {
    var task = iter.current.value;

    if (task.name === taskName) {
        taskRegistered = true;
        break;
    }

    iter.moveNext();
}

if (taskRegistered) {
    successCallback(); // my javascript success callback
} else {
    Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.BackgroundExecutionManager.requestAccessAsync().then(function () {
        var builder = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.BackgroundTaskBuilder();

        builder.name = taskName;
        builder.taskEntryPoint = "CordovaApp.Library.UploadTask";
        builder.setTrigger(new Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.TimeTrigger(15, false));
        builder.addCondition(new Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.SystemCondition(Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.SystemConditionType.internetAvailable));

        return builder.register();
    }).done(function () {
        successCallback();
    }, function (err) {
        errorCallback(err);
    });
}
```

Why is this not working?  If i ran the task manually using visual studio it fails over on this line and it fails over on this line if i let the backgroundTask run itself after 15 minutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

I added the async keyword to my backgroundTask Run method so i could call my async method.

Instead of this, i removed the async keywork from my background Run method, and called the async code using

```
var result = Task.Run(async() => {
    return myAsyncMethod();
}).Result;
```

Now all working

Comment: The Result call is the classic ASP.NET deadlock. You worked around it this way. It's usually better to use await all the way up the call chain.

Comment: @usr Why does this happen? Is it a bug in the framework? More info is appreciated.

Comment: @SepehrM we get multiple such questions here per week. Result waits for the task to complete. The task can only complete when it has posted to the current sync context. The sync context is only released after the Result call is done.

Comment: @usr Can you point me to a documentation or an article thoroughly describing this matter?

Comment: @SepehrM https://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en&gws_rd=ssl#complete=1&hl=en&q=asp.net+await+deadlock there you go.